# Get PHP captcha value by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to make some kind of JavaScript validation. I have been using some PHP script to generate captcha code. 
My Dom is:

```
<img src="http://examle.com/captcha_code_file.php?rand=1846368456" name="6_letters_code" id="captchaimg">
```

Is there a way to grab number 1846368456 and compere with input field?

Will it work something like this:

```
var a = document.getElementById("captchaimg");
var b = a. val();
```

Comment: it's a url. you grab the `src` attribute and parse out the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a.val()` wouldn't be valid javascript either. If the element had a value attribute the proper syntax would be `a.value`. To grab the source element use `a.src`. Then you need to parse out the random number:

```
var src = a.src;
var match = src.match(/rand=(\d+)$/);
var rand = match.length > 1 ? match[1] : null;
```

What this is doing is taking the src value and matching off the last term rand=NUMBER. Since we wrapped the `\d+` in `()` it will match to that value in the second element of the match array.

For more information on match see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match There is also a link for regular expressions there as well.

Comment: tnx work great but here i have other problem this number isnt equal to captch code which is showned on screen? In Dom i got number 1846368456 and on screen numbers with letters for example Ax9BkY

Comment: you would need to look at how the captch code is generated and ensure that it is the same as the random number you are passing.

Comment: yes i have PHP script which generates code. Then i start session and store code in it. I created validation in CodeIgniter via PHP, but guy witch work on frontend, told me make JavaScript validation. Is it possible to do that, in first place?

Comment: you could get the value of the inputbox that contains the user entered captcha value. Make an ajax call back to your php and have it validate the value. But unless you know the captcha value on the client side, which if it's not that random number you are generating, then not as far as I know.

Comment: its no use makking java Script validation